# Make item on CSS grid a hyperlink

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I am working with the CSS grid. I thought that I could make one single grid item to a hyperlink, if I wrapped it in an `a` tag. But I can see that this solution is not working.

The whole grid consist of around 30 grid elements made with the CSS grid. Building the grid up with flex boxes is therefore not a good solution.

Does anybody have an idea on how I can turn the whole grid column into a hyperlink?

```css
.item2 {
  grid-row: 1 / 1;
  grid-column: 7/13;
  height: 340px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-image: url("https://vouzalis.dk/Static/Cms/3cb56b7b-b099-487e-a160-f288ade024f7.jpg");
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com">
  <div class="item2 bg-img">
    <a href="sbp-tag">FEATURED</a>
    <a class="sbp-title light-font" href="https://www.google.com">Go to Google</a>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: You mix grid and `flex`

Comment: The flex is for placing the text. Is that not correct?

Comment: you are not allowed to put `a` inside another `a`, this is breaking your layout (remove the inner `a` and the outer one will work fine)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Afif: The question is not about having a anchor inside of another a anchor, so I do not understand the dublicate. The question is how I am making elements made with CSS grid into hyperlinks, without using flex for the elements.

Comment: you said `I wrapped it in an a tag. But I can see that this solution is not working.` --> it's not working because you have nested `a`, the duplicate explain why your code is invalid. it's not about grid or flexbox. Nothing will work if you don't remove the nesting `a`. This is your issue which is covered by the duplicate

Comment: The a tag inside an a tag is not answering the question. Please read the headline of my question: "Make item on CSS grid a hyperlink". This question is not answered yet. The answer is not because there is an a tag inside an a tag.

Comment: you should then edit your question.  First there is no grid in your code and second you are writing an invalid HTML (like it's described in the duplicate). So whataver your will do, your code is invalid because you have a nested `a` thus the duplicate. If the duplicate doesn't solve your issue, edit your question to better show your real issue and the question ca be reopened. In its actual state the question is a perfect duplicate.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I agree with the criticism that wrapping an `a` inside an `a` is invalid, but the crux of the question here is how to make a grid item a link; substantial changes to OP's code are necessary anyway, so solutions can include a fix for that X/Y problem as well.

Comment: @TylerH but I am still convinced by the duplicate because it seems the only issue here. He already applied `a` to the grid item but it's not working due to the nested `a`. Removing the inner `a` will make the outer one to work fine ... if it still not working, the OP need to include an MCVE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You want to use `grid` **but** you use `flex` so change the `dispaly` to [`grid`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)

   **OR**
   If you want to use `flex` use without the `grid-column/row`
2. Use `wrap` div and set [`href`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp) on **click** to demo link use `cursor: pointer;`

```css
.wrap{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.item2 {
      grid-row: 1 / 1;
      grid-column: 7/13;
      height: 340px;
      display: grid;
      background-image: url("https://vouzalis.dk/Static/Cms/3cb56b7b-b099-487e-a160-f288ade024f7.jpg");
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrap" onclick='location.href = "https://www.w3schools.com";'>
      <div class="item2 bg-img">
        <a href="sbp-tag">FEATURED</a>
        <a class="sbp-title light-font" href="https://www.google.com">Go to Google</a>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, `item2` is a grid item, so its not that OP misplaced it with `display: flex`

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your suggestion. The flex is used for placing the text, so I guess I cannot change that?

Comment: so use `flex` without `grid-row/column`

Comment: Argh that would not be a good solution to use flex instead of the grid. The grid consist of around 30 grid boxes made with the CSS grid. So using flex for this is not a good solution.

Comment: @Mv27 you can nest flex content inside of grid without issue.