# Make CSS grid element a hyperlink

Tags: html, css

I am really not sure on how to make a grid element a hyperlink anno 2019 standard. I need the grid element `<div class="item1">` to be a hyperlink.

How am I doing that the best way?

**Code Example**

```css
.item1 {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  grid-column: 1/7;
  height: 700px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-image: url("/Cms/ea8d405c-d794-4616-9b16-c921a76c43a2.jpg");
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item1">
    <span>TAG</span>
    <span class="sbp-title light-font" href="#">Read More</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: instead of `div` make it `a` (and remove the `a` inside) .. as a side note you are repeating the same unclear question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54967009/8620333

Comment: what is u r requirement ?

Comment: You have two links inside it already. You can't nest links. I think you need to describe your problem in more detail.

Comment: @Quentin: Thanks for your reply. I just edited my question. I changed the `a href` tags to a span tag. I need to make `<div class="item1">`a hyperlink. I can nest all the item1 in an a tag, but then my `.item1`class is not working.

Comment: @Mv27 hey that is a sample code you can change the code as u need ! 
,why dont u use anchor tag inside span as the first exmaple. you can dynamically generate those things.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions there came. All of them has been deleted because of a wrong standard of doing it. So if anybody else have a suggestion, I would be happy to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an hyperlink, the tag `<a>` is required even if javascript can give you the opportunitie to attach an `onclick` event to anything, mind that your html document should still make sense without CSS an JavaScript. (screen readers and search engines will be gratefull to you).

What would be there to do first is to turn the `span` into a real link so the linked document can be found if it stands elsewhere and needs to be open.

Note there is others methods if you want to load some extra text inside your document, javascript and form elements or onclick events to send a request to the server or even CSS to hide / show a portion of text.

easy CSS and HTML possibilities

- `span` turned into a link and a pseudo element to cover the whole parent

```css
.item1 {
  position: relative;
}

.item1 a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.item1 {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  grid-column: 1/7;
  height: 80vh; /* update for demo purpose */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-image: url("/Cms/ea8d405c-d794-4616-9b16-c921a76c43a2.jpg");
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item1">
    <span>TAG</span>
    <a class="sbp-title light-font" href="#">Read More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

- Or turn the parent DIV into a real link Note, no other link nor form elements can be nested

```css
.item1 {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  grid-column: 1/7;
  height: 80vh;  /* update for demo purpose */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-image: url("/Cms/ea8d405c-d794-4616-9b16-c921a76c43a2.jpg");
}


/* mind css styling outline, color, underline ... */
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a class="item1" href="#">
    <span>TAG</span>
    <span class="sbp-title light-font">Read More </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

---

If you expect something else than just linking to another page, you may consider javaScript / ajax and eventually form elements. Anyway, make sure the content you want to show can be reach.

---

If the text you want to show is hidden and part of this document, CSS can help you to show it . If that is the case update your question so we can show you what can be done.